# Community User - Edit Contact Record/Change Account

Tags: community, sharing, sharing-sets

I have a Customer Community with sharing set up in a way that allows Community Users to edit their own Contact record. I am able to change every single field on the Contact record when logged in as a Community User, with the exception of one: Account Lookup.

I suspect this is a security precaution. Sharing Sets grant elevated access, and can work based off of which Account your Contact record belongs to. If you can change your Account, you get access to a different set of records.

Is this possible? If not, is there documentation that outlines why it isn't possible? I haven't been able to find anything.

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible. When you create a customer community user, the user's role is determined by his/her contact's account owner's role.

This determines the level of access the customer community user has on the contacts of his account and other related records. If you change the account on the contact, then the whole roles, access and sharing or related records need to be revoked from the old account and need to be created in new account which is cumbersome.

I could find this [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=networks_create_external_users.htm) mentioning about the roles.

> The available profiles for external users are limited to the Partner
>   Community User profile or profiles cloned from it. Unlike a standard
>   user, the partner user role is automatically assigned based on the
>   account name. The partner user role is a subordinate of the account
>   owner’s role. Therefore, all data for the partner user role rolls up
>   to the partner account owner’s role. If you disable a partner user,
>   the partner user role becomes obsolete, and the data no longer rolls
>   up to the partner account role.

Comment: These are Customer Community licensed Users, not Partner Community users.

Comment: I added that documentation for reference how roles are based on Account to give more points why you cannot change account.