# Can a community user edit their own contact record?

Tags: community, permissions, contact, documentation

Can a community user edit their own contact record?

I've seen few question on the stack exchange it self about community user's editing their own contact record's details directly.

Somehow could't find a reference to a salesforce documentation. Could some one help me to confirm whether the community users can or cannot change their own contact record.

I found below idea explaining a workaround:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000006tto

and some 
sfse questions;
[Community User - Edit Contact Record/Change Account](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/117638/community-user-edit-contact-record-change-account)
[Allow contact to edit own record in customer community](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/174432/allow-contact-to-edit-own-record-in-customer-community)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible through the profile in my research on stack. You can read the full answer here >> [Salesforce Communities - Records Access](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/334589/salesforce-communities-records-access)

You have to go to Setup > Digital Experiences > Settings

Once you are in there you need to create a `Sharing Set`. This will allow you to then Set the read write permissions and target contact for the community.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Short answer yes, this is possible. It will require setting up the profile permissions on the Contact to give the field access, sharing settings to set which contact records they can see and edit, normally private.

Comment: Could you add any more info on how to go about doing that?

Comment: This answer is not valid for community users.