# Salesforce Communities - Records Access

Tags: community, sharing, sharing-rule

How can I grant Community Users read access to all accounts and contacts, but only edit access to the logged-in user contact and related account? We have Community User licenses only.

Comment: Use sharing settings and differentiate access for Internal and External users. Best practice is to restrict using Organisation wide defaults(OWD) and open up access using sharing rules.

Comment: My understanding is that Sharing Rules are not available with Community User licenses. I have set External Sharing Settings to Public Read Only which allows all Community users to see all accounts & contacts, but it does not give a logged-in user the ability to edit its own contact or related-account data.

Comment: We are using Customer Community Plus licenses and we can set sharing rules based on Portal roles. Are you saying that the internal users cannot edit their own contacts or accounts? Is the record owner the one who created the record or someone above the user's role hierarchy assigned with automation?

Comment: Sharing rules are not available for Customer Community licenses - only Customer Community Plus licenses. So, I had to use Sharing Sets

Answer (score 4):

As you are using Customer Community licences you need to use Sharing Sets to allow edit access to their related accounts. Customer Community Plus licences use the standard sharing model unlike high volume licences such as Customer Community.

Sharing Sets can be maintained under Digital Experiences>Settings>Sharing Sets. You can create one or multiple sharing sets and set the permission for the Customer Community profiles to be able to update the Accounts and Contacts related to their user records by granting Read/Write access. See image below

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I added a Sharing Set and it works. I set Account to User:Account = Account:Id and set Contact to User:Contact = Contact:Id with Read/Write Access Level.

Comment: Now, I have one more issue. How do I remove the Edit button from the Accounts and Contacts that should not be editable, but leave the Edit button for the Account & Contact that should be editable for the logged-in user?

Comment: Any idea on the Edit button?